# TreeView with two collections per model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I have a class that has two collections and I need to show that in my tree.

```
class Test
{
     ObservableCollection<Test> ReplacementOptions {get; set;}
     ObservableCollection<Test> Given {get; set;}
     public String Name {get; set;}
}
```

Right now I only know how to create it with ReplacementOptions:

```
    <TreeView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="DefaultEquipmentTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedUnit.DefaultEquipment}" PreviewMouseRightButtonUp="OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ReplacementOptions}" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <xmlEditor:BindableSelectedItemBehavior SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDefaultEquipment, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TreeView>
```

How would I be able to accomplish showing both collections recursively in the tree with MVVM?

Example:

As you can see, each Test has a 2 Collections of Tests.

```
Test1 //Name
--Replacement //Replacements. for the collection name
   -- Test2 //Then that lists each Test Name in that collection
        --Replacements //then that Collection has both Collections... etc
             --Test4
        --Given

--Given // Given
 --Test3
    --Replacements(empty collection)
    --Given(empty collection)
```

Comment: How they would be presented, sequentially, or in a union-like fashion ?

Comment: I updated the post with an example.

Comment: Sorry, can't wrap my head with your 3rd code block, it looks recursive but ... what exactly is this tree supposed to do/help you at ?

Comment: I have data structure I need to view. Look at the class, how it has two collections of its own type. I don't know the size until runtime.

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't solve my original problem, this is a workaround.

Get rid of the TreeView and use a ListView:

```
<ListView  x:Name="DefaultEquipmentTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedUnit.DefaultEquipment}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDefaultEquipment, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EquipmentTemplate}"/>
```

The Template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="EquipmentTemplate" DataType="models:Equipment">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Replacement Options:" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
        <ListView Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding ReplacementOptions}" Margin="15,0,0,0" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDefaultEquipment, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource MainViewModel}}"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="Given:" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
        <ListView Grid.Row="4" ItemsSource="{Binding GivenEquipment}" Margin="15,0,0,0" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDefaultEquipment, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource MainViewModel}}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```